# C++11 Do all control paths still need to return a value?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

This my seem like a ridiculous question but today I wrote a member function in C++ that is supposed to return and int but doesn't always. I even wrote a really simple function that doesn't return a value...

```
int derp()
{
    if (11 == 22) return 0;
}
```

Is this a recent change? is my compiler broken? lol

EDIT: this does compile btw

Comment: On x86 return values are usually what value the `eax` register holds, and that value will depend on how the compiler chose to use it in your function. So its value/behaviour will likely differ from compiler to compiler, and from changing compilation settings. i.e. undefined. As for your code it could be that, depending how you use the return value of this function, the compiler optimiser strips it out and ignores it, and so you get no warnings.

Comment: What do you actually mean with "recent change?"

Answer (score 7):

In a non-void function all control paths must return. The key issue here is that the compiler is not required to diagnose it. Note that *compile* and *is correct* are not necessarily the same. All *correct* code compiles, but not all code that compiles is *correct*.

Comment: i see, i couldv'e sworn this would've been a compile error before.

Comment: @DavidCarpenter: The compiler can (*should*) diagnose it, but it is not required.

Comment: @DavidCarpenter if you compiler with GCC and the `-Wall` flag you would get a warning.

Comment: @DavidCarpenter: Ensure your warning levels are appropriately high.

Comment: Are you thinking of "Flowing off the end of a function is equilalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function." (somewhere in 6.6.3) ? It's fine not to return anything in any path as long as it doesn't actually happen when the program runs. Even the example in the OP is fine as long as the function is not called (which makes it a pathological example I suppose).

Answer (score 4):

No, C++ never required all control paths to return a value. It's valid in C++11 and C++03 as well (syntactically).

Some compilers *can* detect most situations where you're missing a return, but a diagnostics is not required. Most will not issue a diagnostic if there's at least a control path that returns.

Regardless, it's UB.

Comment: so is the return value considered "undefined" in that case?

Comment: @DavidCarpenter it is the act of calling a value-returning function that "flows off the end" that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: i might have hit it by accident, sorry

Comment: @DavidCarpenter - if you hit it by accident you can undo it.

Comment: You are saying not all control paths need to return a value, @David Rodríguez - dribeas says the opposite, I wonder what's true. ;)